# how can I get the not null last value in a relational table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the last value in a relational table, but it will be not null.
The tables are the following:

```
1 - Invoices
Invoice  Date          Vendor       Amount
A1       2018-08-10    John          150
A2       2018-08-12    Paul          250
A3       2018-08-15    Henry         180

2 - Payments
Check   DateP          Invoice      Vendor     AmountP
101     2018-09-01       A1          John        150
102     2018-09-01       A2          Paul        250
103     2018-09-15       A1          John        150
104     2018-09-10       A3          Henry       180
105     2018-09-10       A3          Henry       180
```

The result should be like this:

```
Check   DateP          Invoice      Vendor     AmountP
102     2018-09-01       A2          Paul        250
103     2018-09-15       A1          John        150
105     2018-09-10       A3          Henry       180
```

Can you help me, please.

Comment: Can you add some "null values" to your example, to better understand what do you mean?

Comment: and dbms needed to be added

Comment: What's the database engine? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: by the way, no need to multiplex the same values for both tables.

Comment: The Impaler. The database engine is SQL Server. 
The null values appear to me when I execute the Max function, I need to get the last not null value

Comment: The sample data doesn't help much without any null values. Are you saying there are payments with a null amount in the table? Why do you even allow that? Why not make the column not nullable? And I suppose there is an amount in the payments table, because it can be different from the invoice table? So an invoice can be payed in parts? And in that case you only want to show the last part payment? And Henry payed mistakenly twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want the last payment per invoice. You can use `row_number()`, if your DBMS supports it.

```
SELECT check,
       datep,
       invoice,
       vendor,
       amountp
       FROM (SELECT check,
                    datep,
                    invoice,
                    vendor,
                    amountp,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY invoice
                                       ORDER BY datep DESC) rn
                    FROM elbat) x
       WHERE rn = 1;
```

Replace `ORDER BY datep DESC` with `ORDER BY check DESC` if `check` defines the order, not `datep`, which I assumed.

Comment: How should I write the code in left outer join:            left outer join  (select 
   [APTran].[CheckNum],
   [APTran].[TranDate],
   [APTran].[InvoiceNum] ,
   [APTran].[VendorNum] ,
  [APTran].[LegalNumber]  
 
 from (SELECT APTran.CheckNum,
                    APTran.TranDate,
                    APTran.InvoiceNum,
                    APTran.VendorNum,
                    APTran.LegalNumber,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY APTran.InvoiceNum ORDER BY APTran.CheckNum DESC) rn
                    FROM Erp.APTran as APTran) x
       WHERE rn = 1

Comment: @alerodrigueziv: You can enclose the whole thing in parenthesis (remove the `;` of course), give it an alias and use it like a normal table. Like `... LEFT JOIN (<my query>) <alias> ON ...`. Refer to it via the alias.

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit , I solved the problem with your advice

Answer (score 0):

you may try [***this***](http://rextester.com/GRIKQE92792):

```
select max(p.[check]) as [check] , max(p.DateP) as DateP, p.Invoice, p.Vendor, p.AmountP
  from Payments p
 inner join Invoices i on (i.Invoice = p.Invoice )
 group by p.Invoice, p.Vendor, p.AmountP
 order by [check];

check      DateP  Invoice   Vendor  AmountP
 102    01.09.2018   A2      Paul    250
 103    15.09.2018   A1      John    150
 105    10.09.2018   A3      Henry   180
```

p.s. check is a reserved keyword, for this reason I've wrapped up in square brackets.

Comment: I'd prefer to use square brackets to double quotes. It's less confusing for those who know other languages. SELECT MAX(p.[check]) as [check] is much more readable and understandable, and doesn't depend on anything like the QUOTED IDENTIFIERS setting.

Comment: Thanks @BarbarosÖzhan, I solved the problem with your advice